# Adding ActiveMQ-rar to a payara micro 6.2022.2 docker image.causes error javax/resource/spi/ActivationSpec

Tags: java, docker, activemq-classic, payara, payara-micro

SO I am currently getting an issue while trying to add my active mq adapter to my docker image.

I am building the image from scratch and bringing in the activeMQ.rar

My enviroment is
image : openjdk:17-alpine
maven : 3.9.0
java : 17
payara-micro-6.2022.2
activemq-rar:5.17.3

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine

ENV PAYARA_MICRO_DIR /opt/payara/

COPY maven/startup/prebootcommands.txt /opt/cmd/prebootcommands.txt
COPY maven/startup/payara-micro-6.2022.2.jar /opt/payara/payara-micro-6.2022.2.jar
COPY maven/startup/activemq-rar.rar /opt/payara/activemq-rar.rar
```

I then warm up the payara and set the exec cmd

```
RUN java -jar /opt/payara/payara-micro.jar  --disablephonehome --prebootcommandfile /opt/cmd/prebootcommands.txt  --nocluster --addlibs /opt/libs --postbootcommandfile /opt/cmd/portal-setup.txt --warmup --rootdir /opt/payara/domains --deploy /opt/payara/activemq-rar.rar

CMD exec \
java -jar -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009 -DTargetDatabase=${TARGET_DB} -jar /opt/payara/payara-micro.jar \
--disablephonehome \
--enablehealthcheck true \
--nocluster \
--postbootcommandfile /opt/cmd/postbootscript.txt \
--addlibs /opt/libs \
--name ${HOSTNAME} \
--postdeploycommandfile /opt/cmd/postdeploy.asadmin \
--deploy /opt/payara/activemq-rar.rar
```

When I compose the image I am currently getting a javax/resource/spi/ActivationSpec

```
[2023-02-15T12:54:35.892+0000] [] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1676465675892] [levelValue: 1000] [[
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893215648Z   javax/resource/spi/ActivationSpec
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893218341Z java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.spi.ActivationSpec
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893220712Z  at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:806)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893223103Z  at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:688)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893225504Z  at com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorClassFinder.findClass(ConnectorClassFinder.java:85)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893227945Z  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:586)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893230760Z  at com.sun.enterprise.loader.CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.loadClass(CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.java:83)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893233827Z  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893248525Z  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893251299Z  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893254033Z  at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:746)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893256475Z  at com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorClassFinder.findClass(ConnectorClassFinder.java:85)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893258311Z  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:586)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893260954Z  at com.sun.enterprise.loader.CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.loadClass(CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.java:83)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893263546Z  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893265362Z  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893267662Z  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893270245Z  at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:746)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893272535Z  at com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorClassFinder.findClass(ConnectorClassFinder.java:85)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893274885Z  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:586)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893277084Z  at com.sun.enterprise.loader.CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.loadClass(CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.java:83)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893279284Z  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893282653Z  at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.deployment.util.ConnectorValidator.getClass(ConnectorValidator.java:242)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893284994Z  at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.deployment.util.ConnectorValidator.validateActivationSpec(ConnectorValidator.java:155)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893287314Z  at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.deployment.util.ConnectorValidator.accept(ConnectorValidator.java:79)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893289725Z  at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.deployment.util.ConnectorValidator.accept(ConnectorValidator.java:72)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893292106Z  at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:618)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893294557Z  at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.deployment.util.ConnectorArchivist.postOpen(ConnectorArchivist.java:173)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893297039Z  at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.deployment.util.ConnectorArchivist.postOpen(ConnectorArchivist.java:72)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893299298Z  at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.openWith(Archivist.java:294)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893301780Z  at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openWith(ApplicationFactory.java:232)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893304736Z  at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:211)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893307076Z  at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:246)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893312484Z  at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:97)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893314965Z  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1161)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893317356Z  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployers(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1129)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893319868Z  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:944)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893324105Z  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:453)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893326950Z  at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:612)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893329341Z  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893331732Z  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:552)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893334082Z  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893336887Z  at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:365)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893340771Z  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:551)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893343172Z  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:582)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893345805Z  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:574)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893348327Z  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893351555Z  at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:365)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893354006Z  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:573)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893357416Z  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1497)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893359676Z  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1869)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893361956Z  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1755)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893364468Z  at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:131)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893366697Z  at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:104)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893368846Z  at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.deployAll(PayaraMicroImpl.java:1739)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893371116Z  at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.bootStrap(PayaraMicroImpl.java:1092)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893373446Z  at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.create(PayaraMicroImpl.java:236)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893375726Z  at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.main(PayaraMicroImpl.java:223)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893381466Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893383776Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893386107Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893388518Z  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893390787Z  at fish.payara.micro.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:50)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893393007Z  at fish.payara.micro.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:114)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893395246Z  at fish.payara.micro.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:73)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893397476Z  at fish.payara.micro.boot.PayaraMicroLauncher.create(PayaraMicroLauncher.java:88)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893399675Z  at fish.payara.micro.boot.PayaraMicroLauncher.main(PayaraMicroLauncher.java:72)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893401814Z  at fish.payara.micro.PayaraMicro.main(PayaraMicro.java:467)
2023-02-15T12:54:35.893404154Z ]]
```

It works on a lower jdk images but with payara 5 not 6.

Comment: Any feedback here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your don't have the right jars in your classpath. Here's the root cause of your problem:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.spi.ActivationSpec
```

This is part of the Java EE specification and should be furnished to any JCA resource adapter by your container.

You appear to be using Payara's implementation of "MicroProfile" which, to my knowledge, does *not* include JCA.